# Change the selection state of the litstbox item when a user clicks on a button (ZK 3.6.4)

Tags: listbox, zk, zul

I'm working in a project with ZK 3.6.4. but I have a problem, I want to change the selection state of the   litstbox  item when a user clicks on a button inside the same listbox ( same listitem)., because I want to know the selectedItem.  I was reading zk documentation and I can do it , but with Zk version 5.0.5+ (nonselectableTags). But I cannot change for this version for project rules. So, there are a way to emulate this behavior with 3.6.4? or what kind of advices can  you give  me to do this? I really appreciate your help.

Here the code that I have.

```
<listbox
    id="listDocAcads" mold="paging" pageSize="2"
    model="@{win$composer.academicCollections}"
    selectedItem="@{controller.docEntAcad}" >
    <listhead>
        <listheader
            width="30%" label="Name" />
        <listheader
            width="15%" label="amount" />
        <listheader
            width="15%" label=" delivered?" />
        <listheader
            width="20%" label="Importance" />
        <listheader
            width="20%" label="Document" />
    </listhead>
    <listitem
        self="@{each='docAcad'}" value="docAcad"
        style="border:none;">
        <listcell
            label="@{docAcad.colleByProcess.oDocument.name}" />
        <listcell
            label="@{docAcad.colleByProcess.amount}" />
        <listcell>
            <spinner
                width="60%" value="@{docAcad.amount}" />
        </listcell>
        <listcell
            label="@{docAcad.colleByProcess.oImportance.name}" />
        <listcell ><button id="btnUploadDocument"  label="Upload"/> </listcell>
    </listitem>
</listbox>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to ignore button and input's u can do this.
nonselectableTags="button, input".

```
<listbox nonselectableTags="button, input">
    <listitem><listcell><textbox/></listcell></listitem>
    <listitem><listcell><button label="button"/></listcell></listitem>
    <listitem><listcell><h:input xmlns:h="native"/></listcell></listitem>
    <listitem><listcell><datebox/></listcell></listitem>
</listbox>
```

the values to nonselectableTags should be HTML tags separated by comma.

Hope this helps!